# Python scheduler not running a function scheduled in an import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, scheduler

### Problem

When this block of code:

```py
# main.py - this file gets run directly.
import sched
import time
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

print("before definition")

def do_something():
    print("do_something is being executed.")
    scheduler.enter(1, 5, do_something)

print("post definition")
scheduler.enter(1, 5, do_something)

# Do something, so that the program does not terminate.
do_not_terminate()
```

is in the file being invoked (*main.py*) it runs as expected(with the do_something function being run every second.), producing the following output:

```
before definition
post definition
do_something is being executed.
do_something is being executed.
do_something is being executed.
do_something is being executed.
do_something is being executed.
do_something is being executed.
...
```

#### But:

when the above block is put into a separate file (*someimport.py*) and *someimport.py* gets imported in *main.py* the do_something function no longer gets executed. [The code looks like this:]

```py
# someimport.py - this file gets imported in main.py
import sched
import time
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

print("before definition")

def do_something():
    print("do_something is being executed.")
    scheduler.enter(1, 5, do_something)

print("post definition")
scheduler.enter(1, 5, do_something)
```

```py
# main.py - this file get's run directly
import someimport

# Do something, so that the program does not terminate.
do_not_terminate()
```

Only the following output is produced (and of course no error messages appear):

```
before definition
post definition
```

#### I already tried the following:

1. Switch `import someimport` to `from someimport import *` in *main.py*

This, as somewhat expected, did not change anything.

2. Put the first *scheduler.enter* call into a separate function(*run*), which is called after the import:

```py
# someimport.py - this file gets imported in main.py
import sched
import time
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

print("before definition")

def do_something():
    print("do_something is being executed.")
    scheduler.enter(1, 5, do_something)

print("post definition")
def run():
    scheduler.enter(1, 5, do_something)
```

```py
# main.py - this file get's run directly
import someimport

someimport.run()

# Do something, so that the program does not terminate.
do_not_terminate()
```

This did not change anything.

3. importing *sched* and *time* in *main.py* aswell.

As expected, this also did not have any effect.

Is there any way to schedule the do_something function in *someimport.py*, without having the first *scheduler.enter* in the main.py file.
That is the thing I'm trying to avoid (as in the real project there are ~100 scheduled tasks like this and I'm trying to clean up the main file).

The all the code above has been tested on python 3.7.3 under GNU/Linux.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your separate module example working only by calling `run()` on the `scheduler` instance after importing it into main.py.

```
# main.py - this file get's run directly
import someimport

someimport.scheduler.run()  # Blocks until all events finished
```

Produces:

```
before definition
post definition
do_something is being executed.
do_something is being executed.
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.run), `scheduler.run()` has to be called in order to run any scheduled tasks. The `scheduler.enter()` method on it's own will just schedule events, not run them.

Comment: Thank you! When separating out the function, I forgot to call scheduler.run().